# Sum of two ideals $I=<a,b>, J=<c,d>$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Sum of ideals $I_j$ is defined by $\sum_{j \in J} I_j=<\cup_{j \in J} I_j>$. I'm not really sure how to use this definition in, for example, sum of ideals $I=<a,b>, J=<c,d>$. How should I write it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$ I + J =\ <a, b, c, d>$.